# Background Image is not scrolling along with Table

Tags: html, css, background

```
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #heading {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    table {
        border-color: black;
        margin-top: 30px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background-color: lightgrey;
        opacity: 0.9;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    table tr td {
        padding: 7px;
    }

    input {
        border-color: black;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    #male {
        margin-left: 6px;
    }

    #female {
        margin-left: 6px;
    }

    #rfemale {
        margin-left: 6px;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
    }

    /* Button Styled */

    button {
        border: 2px solid grey;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 7px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    /* Background Image Styled */
    .bg::before {
        background-image: url("pexels-eva-bronzini-7956852.jpg");
        background-size: 45% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: local;
        position: absolute;
        background-position: center;
        content: "";
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: -1;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    label {
        font-weight: bold;
    } </style>

<body>
    <center>
        <div id="heading">
            <h1>
                Employee Details
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="underline">
            ==========================
        </div>
        <form>
            <table border="2px">

                <!-- Employee Number -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Employee Number</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your number"></td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Employee Name -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Employee Name</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required></td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Gender -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Gender</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="gender"><label id="male">Male</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="rfemale" name="gender"><label id="female">Female</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- D . O . B -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>D.O.B</label>
                    </td>

                    <td><input type="date" name="DOB" id="DOB"></td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Department Number -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Department Number</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><select name="DepNo">
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="30">30</option>
                            <option value="40">40</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Department Name -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Department Name</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="depname" id="depname">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Sales Marketing -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Sale Marketing</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><select name="SalesMarketing">
                            <option value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
                            <option value="Wholesaling">Wholesaling</option>
                            <option value="Retailing">Retailing</option>
                            <option value="Packaging">Packaging</option>
                            <option value="Transport">Transport</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                <tr>
                    <!-- Contact Number -->
                    <td>
                        <label>Contact Number</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="mob" name="mobile" id="mobile"></td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Email Id -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Email Id</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="email" name="Emailid" id="Emailid"></td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Password -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Password</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="Password" id="Password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Enter Date and Time</label></td>
                    <td><input type="datetime-local"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Insert A File</label></td>
                    <td><input type="file"></td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Hobbies Checkbox -->
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Check your hobbies</label></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox">Painting
                        <br>
                        <input type="checkbox">Drawing
                        <br>
                        <input type="checkbox">Gaming
                        <br>
                        <input type="checkbox">Singing
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Submit and Reset Buttons -->
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
                    <td align="center"><button type="reset">Reset</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <!-- Background Image -->
        <div class="bg"></div>
    </center>
```

I created a table within form tag and added a background with class named .bg and styled it using Internal CSS with other elements styled with their related Classes and Ids.
I want the background image to be scrollable to the bottom of the webpage as that of the table. I tried using the " background-attachment: scroll; " property in the bg::before property but it failed to serve the result.

Answer (score 1):

Add image to your table as background image. Change your table CSS as below

```
table {
        background-image: url("pexels-eva-bronzini-7956852.jpg");
        border-color: black;
        margin-top: 30px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background-color: lightgrey;
        opacity: 0.9;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

You can add other properties to your table.

Comment: Yes, this is true for the table content but I want the body's background image to be scrollable.

Comment: In that case in style change your `.bg::before` with `body` and remove `background-size` property. Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

just use `fixed` position not `absolute`

```css
.bg::before {
  background-image: url("pexels-eva-bronzini-7956852.jpg");
  background-size: 45% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: local;
  position: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  content: "";
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Actually position:fixed; made the entire content contained in the same block including any future element like p tag. So I just discovered min-height worked for me! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to scroll the background with your table you should use position:fixed;

edit this in your code

Your code

```
 body {
        background-image: url("pexels-eva-bronzini-7956852.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: local;
        position: absolute;
        background-position: center;
        content: "";
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: -1;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

The correct is

.

```
bg::before {
            background-image: url("pexels-eva-bronzini-7956852.jpg");
            background-size: 45% 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: local;
            position: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            content: "";
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: -1;
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

and change your table css codet to

```
table {
        background-image: url("pexels-eva-bronzini-7956852.jpg");
        border-color: black;
        margin-top: 30px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background-color: lightgrey;
        opacity: 0.9;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

Comment: It's helpful using postion:fixed, but I found out that no matter how many elements I add after the background image, they just stick inside the image even after margin-top so the best alternative I finally discovered was using the min-height property following the background-size declaration already.